# Find small matrix inside a bigger one but don't know how, in python (image attached)

Tags: python, algorithm, numpy, matrix, design-patterns

I have a pattern that I have represented as a list of lists, and also tried as an array using numpy, and I have to find how many times this pattern exists within the bigger one, like this image

[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f4y6j.png)
*In this cas it would be three times :*
Any ideas on how to solve?

Thanks!

(My code)

So far I have done this, but not even sure I am in the right direction. seems too complicated.

```
#Defined both pattern and bigger matrix as a list of lists.

imagen_1 = [[0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
         [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
         [0, 1, 1, 1, 0],
         [1, 1, 0, 1, 1],
         [1, 0, 0, 0, 1]]

imagen_2 = [[1, 1],
         [0, 1]]


# Then tried this logic, but got too complicated to loop.
# At this point I am just trying to check the actual position and the nearest to the right

def repeticiones(original, patron):
 
 if len(patron) > len(original) or len(patron[0]) > len(original[0]):
     raise ValueError(f"La imagen patrón es más grande que la original. Por favor, proporcione una imagen patrón más pequeña a {len(original)} * {len(original[0])}")
 
 c = 0
 
 filas_patron = len(patron)
 columnas_patron = len(patron[0])
 
 j = -1
 i = -1
 
 for linea in range((filas_patron)-2):
     j += 1
     i = -1
     for columna in range((columnas_patron)-2):
         i += 1
         igual = original[j][i]==patron[0][0] and linea[j][i+1]==patron[0][2]
         if igual:
             return True
     
 return False
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Please post your code.

Comment: Let's say A is your numpy matrix. Then use this condition `if(A[x][y]==1 & A[x][y+1]==1 & A[x+1][y]==0 & A[x+1][y+1]==1)` give x and y required limits and try. this is just an idea since I don't have your code.

Answer (score 0):

It is pretty easy, just do a grid search and compare submatrices with the desired pattern:

```
A = np.random.randint(0, 2, size=(10, 12))
P = np.array([[1, 1],
              [0, 0]])
n = 0
for i in range(A.shape[0] - P.shape[0]):
    for j in range(A.shape[1] - P.shape[1]):
        n += np.all(A[i:(i+P.shape[0]), j:(j+P.shape[1])] == P)
print(f"Pattern 'P' found {n} times in 'A'.")
```

Comment: Cool! But I made a mistake and edited it. Pattern is [[1, 1], [0, 1]] insted of what i originally posted. I am trying to adapt your code now

Comment: I am not even sure I have to change the code other than defining my bigger matrix instead of randomizing one. With the pattern and A matrix provided it's saying found 2 times

Comment: Update your code with the updated version to check the mistake.