# Is there a way to check if a dataframe is contained within another?

Tags: python, pandas

I am using pandas to check wether two dataframes are contained within each others. the method `.isin()` is only helpful (e.g., returns `True`) only when labels match (ref: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html) but I want to check further that this to include cases where the labels don't match.

Example: df1:

```
+----+----+----+----+----+
| 3  | 4  | 5  | 6  | 7  |
+----+----+----+----+----+
| 11 | 13 | 10 | 15 | 12 |
+----+----+----+----+----+
| 8  | 2  | 9  | 0  | 1  |
+----+----+----+----+----+
| 14 | 23 | 31 | 21 | 19 |
+----+----+----+----+----+
```

df2:

```
+----+----+
| 13 | 10 |
+----+----+
| 2  | 9  |
+----+----+
```

I want the output to be `True` since `df2` is inside `df1`
Any ideas how to do that using Pandas?

Comment: I don't know of any pandas functions to accomplish this, but you might use a sliding window approach via numpy as in here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73425465/how-can-i-find-if-there-is-a-submatrix-in-a-numpy-matrix with `df1.to_numpy()` and `df2.to_numpy()`

Comment: Similar answer here, using numpy: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66351421/find-small-matrix-inside-a-bigger-one-but-dont-know-how-in-python-image-attac That being said, [this is an interesting angle](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/111124/how-do-i-determine-if-a-matrix-is-contained-in-another-matrix) that is mathmatics based. Not sure if/how it would be solved in python, but may be worth thinking through

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [numpy](/questions/tagged/numpy)'s [`sliding_window_view`](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view.html):

```
from numpy.lib.stride_tricks import sliding_window_view as swv

(swv(df1, df2.shape)==df2.to_numpy()).all((-2, -1)).any()
```

Output: `True`

Intermediate:

```
(swv(df1, df2.shape)==df2.to_numpy()).all((-2, -1))

array([[False, False, False, False],
       [False,  True, False, False],  # df2 is found in position 1,1
       [False, False, False, False]])
```

##### using a partial match

Example 1: ≥ 75% of matches:

```
from numpy.lib.stride_tricks import sliding_window_view as swv

((swv(df1, df2.shape)==df2.to_numpy()).mean((-2, -1))>=0.75).any()
```

Example 2: ≥ 3 matches:

```
from numpy.lib.stride_tricks import sliding_window_view as swv

((swv(df1, df2.shape)==df2.to_numpy()).sum((-2, -1))>=3).any()
```

Alternative input:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame([[13, 10], [2, 8]])
```

Comment: can you explain the purpose of a sliding window view as well as the `all((-2,-1))` and `any()` here ?

Comment: @Sam `swv` is sliding over all rectangles of `df2`'s shape in `df1`. If `all` values are equal, aggregate as True (giving the intermediate shown in my answer). If there is `any` `True` in this intermediate, then `df2` is present inside `df1`. If you use `sum` in place of `any` you can count how many times `df2` is in `df1`.

Comment: could it also find if only a part of df2 is found in df1 ? for example `df1 = [[5, 1,2], [6,3,4]]` and `df2 = [[5, 1], [62, 32]]` then True will be shown because `[5, 1]` is in both?

Comment: It depends what you consider a part. Instead of `all` you could `sum` or `mean` and use the output as an absolute/relative number of matches. See update

Comment: as explained in the previous comment a part of df2 = `[[5, 1], [62, 32]]` which is `[5,1]` is inside df1 = `[[5, 1,2], [6,3,4]]`, I am interested in getting the position of such intersection e.g `[5,1]` inside df1

Comment: Yes but is it because of contiguous columns? because of at least 50% matches?

Comment: yes because of contiguous column

Comment: You cant try `(swv(df1, df2.shape)==df2.to_numpy()).all(-1).any()` to match by full columns. If you want to match either columns or rows, then this is quite a different question, you would need a more complex code.

Answer (score 1):

Check if all the elements in `df2` are present in `df1`. For clarity, below is the initial approach I used that doesn't take order into account and the new one that does, with examples and output.

```
import pandas as pd

data1 = {
    3: [11, 8, 14],
    4: [13, 2, 23],
    5: [10, 9, 31],
    6: [15, 0, 21],
    7: [12, 1, 19]
}

data2 = {
    13: [13, 2],
    10: [10, 9]
}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)

data_unordered_1 = {
    3: [11, 8, 14],
    4: [13, 9, 23],  # Note: Changed value at position (1,4) from 2 to 9
    5: [10, 2, 31],  # Note: Changed value at position (1,5) from 9 to 2
    6: [15, 0, 21],
    7: [12, 1, 19]
}

df3 = pd.DataFrame(data_unordered_1)

# ======================================== #
# X WRONG: does not work for subdataframes that are
# not in the same order as the original dataframe

# Flatten dataframes to 1D arrays
flat_df1 = df1.to_numpy().flatten()
flat_df2 = df2.to_numpy().flatten()
flat_df3 = df3.to_numpy().flatten()

# Check if all elements in the second dataframe are in the first
result = all(elem in flat_df1 for elem in flat_df2)
print(result)  # Output: True

result_unordered = all(elem in flat_df3 for elem in flat_df2)
print(result_unordered)  # Output: True --- should be False


# ======================================== #
# RIGHT: accounts for the case where the subdataframe
# is not in the same order as the original dataframe

def is_subdataframe(df, df2):
    df1_vals, df2_vals = [df.values, df2.values]
    df1_rows, df1_cols = df1_vals.shape
    df2_rows, df2_cols = df2_vals.shape

    for r in range(df1_rows - df2_rows + 1):
        for c in range(df1_cols - df2_cols + 1):
            sub_df1_vals = df1_vals[r:r+df2_rows, c:c+df2_cols]
            if (sub_df1_vals == df2_vals).all():
                return True
    return False


result = is_subdataframe(df1, df2)
print(result)  # Output: True

result = is_subdataframe(df3, df2)
print(result)  # Output: False
```

Comment: thanks, how it could also return the top-left (index,column) coordinates of the intersection dataframe with respect to dataframe df? meaning the top left coordinates of the df2 (intersecting dataframe) with respect to df.